# Laravel 5.4 - @extends not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have two main views in Laravel.

Both are called as follows, in web.php:

```
Route::get('/characters', 'CharacterController@index');
Route::get('/characters/{char_id}', 'CharacterController@viewCharacter');
```

Here's their function in CharacterController:

/characters:

```
public function index()
{



$characters = Character::userChars();

return view('pages.characters', compact('characters') );


}
```

characters/{char_id}:

```
public function viewCharacter ($char_id)

{

    $character = \DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', $char_id)->first();

    return view('pages.view-character', compact('character') );


}
```

/characters works fine. 
It uses

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@endsection
```

All the content loads fine and the CSS displays.

However, characters/{char_id} refuses to work correctly.

It displays the content from @extends but will not render the CSS at all.

This is the blade template for characters/{char_id}:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Template <small>Template Page</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Template 1

                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>








            </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

It is identical to the view that /characters uses, except for what's in the content section.

Here is "master.blade.php":
https://pastebin.com/kjnxc0ms

Thanks!

Comment: `dd()` stops any further execution. Thats the _die_ part of it. The layout isnt rendered because you havent allowed it to render. Is `dd()` **really** what you want here? What are you trying to accomplish by it?

Comment: @Kaspars It is not. I'm only using that to test that the variable was passed in correctly.

I've removed that, I now get the "@extends" content but for some reason it's no rendering any CSS. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Post your `layouts.master` file as well.

Comment: Added @Kaspars. It works fine on /characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `master.blade.php` layout, assets are loaded from the relative url

So for example if your assets are loaded from `assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` and your current url is `example.com/character` then your asset will be loaded from `example.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`. This seems fine so far

But if your url is `example.com/characters/potato` then the asset will be loaded from `example.com/characters/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`. This could easily be identified from a browsers console, since it will show 404 errors when loading assets. (F12 on chrome)

Two solutions to this:

- Prefix your asset paths with a forward slash like so `/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`.
- A laravel specific solution is to use the asset helper function `{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}`.

Comment: Now all my beautiful CSS is back. Thank you very much Kaspars!

Answer (score 1):

First Post you layout code .

second make sure that you call for your css using helper `asset` eg.

```
{{ URL::asset('css/style.css'); }}
```

Comment: Sure, I've added the layout code in a paste-bin at the end. I'll try calling the CSS that way.